# Where are Data Dumps for TGO?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I had always assumed that datadumps for all of the StackExchange sites were Publically available.

I looked at [Posts containing [data-dump] + Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdata-dump%5D+beta) on meta.stackexchange.com and now I am not sure that Beta sites dumped regularly.

Alternately: is there a free app that will allow me to access all the Questions and Answers from TGO when I do not have an internet connection?

Answer (score 4):

Beta sites are included in the quarterly data dump available from [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), most recently updated 2018-03-13. Direct links:

- [Main TGO site](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/outdoors.stackexchange.com.7z) (17.1 MB as of now)
- [Meta TGO](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com.7z) (1.1 MB as of now)

These are exported in XML format and take a fair amount of work and software to become readable, let alone browsable.

As for an app, there is [Stackdump, an offline browser for StackExchange sites](https://stackapps.com/q/3610) but it's a heavy desktop application. I am not aware of any mobile app for offline reading of Stack Exchange sites. Obviously such a thing may be useful for TGO specifically. A homemade solution may be required, likely involving something like bundling the posts into one big PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

If you were okay with just a subset, then what you could do is open the site on a mobile phone with a browser and save the pages for offline reading.

I know that Opera for mobile has this capability, its how I carried the Hornblower series when backpacking.

True story, I asked this question [How can I backpack further without resupplying?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15695/how-can-i-backpack-further-without-resupplying) because I knew the info would come in handy over the summer, got 80 miles out on the Toyabe Crest trail with 50 miles back to the trailhead and dwindling food supplies and could remember that I had asked the question, but couldn't remember the answers.

Comment: This a good solution for specific questions I have [What are the navigation considerations on the Monongahela and Youghiogheny Rivers between Ohiopyle State Park (PA) and Pittsburgh PA?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7239) saved to my Android phone for reference